# When I use FragmentStatePagerAdapter, the fragment won't invoke onCreateView() but loads from the cache if it can

Tags: android

`android.support.v4.app.Fragment` is used, not `android.app.fragment`

Here is the code:

`MaanageActivity.java`

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //x.view().inject(this);
    mAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    managePager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    managePager.setCurrentItem(0);
    managePager.addOnPageChangeListener(this);
    manageOrder.setChecked(true);
    manageBar.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
}
```

`MyFragmentPagerAdapter.java`

```
public class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

private final int PAGER_COUNT = 4;

private ArrayList<Fragment> fragmentArrayList = null;

public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    fragmentArrayList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
    fragmentArrayList.add(new OrderFragment());
    fragmentArrayList.add(new UserFragment());
    fragmentArrayList.add(new ThreeFragment());
    fragmentArrayList.add(new FourFragment());
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return PAGER_COUNT;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return fragmentArrayList.get(position);
}
```

As you can see, the Adapter contains 4 fragments, let's take a look at

`OrderFragment`

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "gg", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    //Do other things...
}
```

When I am in `UserFragment`, I slide left to `OrderFragment`; now that `MyFragmentPagerAdapter` extends `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`,  the `OrderFragment` will be reloaded (invoking onCreateView() etc), so I will see the Toast invoked in `OrderFragment.onViewCreated`.

However the toast doesn't appear as I expect, why? Don't I use the `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` correctly?